# Using Polymer attributes within brackets

Tags: html, css, polymer

Hello I am trying to use the Polymer attributes in css.

This is my code:

```
background: url( {{ image }} );
```

but it doesn't seem to work and outputs

```
url('%7B%7B%20image%20%7D%7D');
```

Comment: might be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987407/polymer-forcing-css-to-load-and-background-image-issues

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Polymer currently supports template binding within a `<style>` tag. You could instead use an inline style attribute on the element, or you could add an imageChanged handler and use the cssom to edit the stylesheet.

Comment: It does work under native Shadow DOM. See https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/270#issuecomment-24683309. But the shadow dom polyfill doesn't support bindings in a `<style>` so you probably want to use an inline `style` attribute like Peter mentioned.